# Ordered list with letters instead of numbers for DITA/Apache-FOP/XML to PDF

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, apache-fop

Here is my XML:

```
<topic>
    <title/>
    <body>
        <ol>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ol>
    </body>
</topic>
```

The output in the PDF, as expected, is:

[image]

But for **ONLY** this particular instance, I want instead of 1. 2., a. b.:

First I added the `outputclass="lower-alpha` to my `<ol>`-tag:

```
<ol outputclass="lower-alpha">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ol>
```

Then I modified my plugin to this (see the box):

[image]

For some reason, this is not working and I am getting the same result.

Any clues?

Thanks,

Comment: Please post **code** that we can use to reproduce your problem - see: [mcve].

Comment: In other words, do not post screenshots of code.